# Laravel Codeception acceptance test coverage routes not recognized

Tags: laravel, codeception

I'm trying to generate code coverage for my controllers using codeception acceptance tests but when I do run the tests with coverage Laravel doesn't know what to do with this route.

`c3.php` is setup and included in `public/index.php` - I've verified the correct page.

```
 [ErrorException] file_get_contents(http://localhost/c3/report/clear): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Are there routes I need to add?

Comment: can you share your acceptance.suite.yml ?

Comment: The provided link is broken and leading to malicious websites. Please remove.

Comment: @fkupper Thanks for that report, link removed.

Comment: @Webnet thanks. Having porn popping up on my screen on my first week in the new job was not nice.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to assess, since there could be a lot of things that might be causing this. I'm not sure it's the routing which is the problem but perhaps the step before that (because it's not a 4xx error).
In Laravel, often when I have a 500 problem and especially in regards to routing (well, mod_rewrite) it often has something to do with my .htaccess file.

Have you tried perhaps adding this line

```
RewriteBase /
```

after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Do not reference this post... SO made me issue the the bounty to an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to get acceptance tests running in Laravel 4.2 is described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/515#issuecomment-93360774).

**codeception.yml**

```
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: false
    c3_url: 'http://whatever.dev/c3.php'
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/c3.php/{extra}', function () {
    require base_path('c3.php');
})->where('extra', '.*');
```

**TIP:**
In the acceptance/functional tests I'm working with I am bootstrapping Laravel as part of the process, so I get full access to Facades and IOC container within the tests which has helped with assertions.

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->boot();
```

> Note: Using `require_once` will not work when generating code coverage.